# Is it necessery to write ScreenUpdating True

Tags: excel, vba

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I found the contradictory statements about the second line.
Is it necessery or not?
Someone says that Excel turns on ScreenUpdating automatically, after each End Sub line?

Comment: It *won't* do it "after each End Sub line", but it *might* do it when the program execution returns back to Excel (from the user/VBA code or macro) .. personally, if this were my code, I'd be explicit and change it back manually, even if Excel did change it back (perhaps to avoid malicious/buggy macros). The [reference for the ScreenUpdating property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221605%28v=office.12%29.aspx) says "*Remember to set the ScreenUpdating property back to True when your macro ends.*"

Comment: @pst You should post it as an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ScreenUpdating should always be set back to True after macro finishes. Plus, don't forget to restore it in case of error, I usually always put Application.ScreenUpdating=True in error hangling code before exit Sub/Function. 
Excel does not apply any automatic setting of this property after macro ends.

Answer (score 0):

Screen updating turns itself back to true when it exists the sub.

Test it out.
Code with screen updating and not set back to true.

```
Sub with_SU2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cell In Range("A1:K22").Cells
        cell.Select
        cell.Value = cell.Row & " _ " & cell.Column
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Run this after the previous code. You will see screen updating has been restored.

```
Sub with_SU()
    For Each cell In Range("A1:K22").Cells
        cell.Select
        cell.Value = cell.Row & " _ " & cell.Column
    Next cell
End Sub
```