# What causes scrolling to be disabled in an excel worksheet?

Tags: excel

I apologize because I feel like I am asking a silly question that I should know the answer to.

I'm wondering what I have done to make it so that one of my worksheets within a workbook does not allow me to scroll.

Some things that might be important

- This worksheet contains command buttons. The command buttons are used to add rows to tables
- One of the command buttons moves all the other command buttons to align them nicely
- this worksheet contains tables

What I have tried and so no change

- I tried duplicating the worksheet and deleting all the command buttons
- In the duplicated worksheet I converted all tables to ranges
- I made sure I didn't have frozen rows/columns

What I tried and maybe learned something?

- I tried selecting all cells and pasting in another page, when I pasted with values I could scroll, when I pasted with sourse formatting I could not. This makes me think it is related to some formatting but I am not sure what specifically.

Answer (score 0):

There're a list of items that could be going on...

- Scroll lock could be on
- You set `.screenupdating=false`
- You are showing a userform that has `mode`
- You have so much memory in use that Excel disabled its display, e.g., you can still `debug.print` in VBA, but the window doesn't scroll while in the instance (and you can save).

Those are some quick heavy hitters, but without having details about what is in your sheet (most of which probably can't be easily shared in a post), nothing can be said definitively.

As such, this is a subjective/speculative question as is and should be closed.

Comment: Thanks @cyril
I just checked and set .screenupdating=true just in case I'd done that but don't see a change. In the fourth instance you mentioned how would I be able to test that? I don't believe I have that much memory in use and I'm happy to share more info if needed.

Comment: @DanicaJacobsson check your task manager (ctrl+shift+esc) memory usage... i have one sheet in a workbook that regularly stops allowing me to scroll (display only), and it's a memory issue, specifically because I have so many calculations being affected on the sheet when I run code to overwrite all of the formulae.  Not fun or ideal, but hand-me-downs are a... yeah.  The memory usage keeps adding up after each run of the macro, and eventually I get that display issue.

Comment: I do never set application.screenupdating = true after I turned it off. It is turned on automatically when the macro is done. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Prema it is not automatically turned back on.  You would have to make that part of your code.  There are several exceptions to this, which includes use of `select` and/or `activate`; however, it would be appropriate to do the toggle off to start and on when finished, to reset your scenario.

Comment: @cyril I tried to prov what you wrote. I did a simple test. The result of the test was: screenupdating is true after the macro is done. Can you prove it remains off after the macro is done? Please let me know, I don't know so much about programming.

Comment: @Prema see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103366/is-it-necessery-to-write-screenupdating-true , specifically the comment to the post, not even the accepted answer.  It's more than just the initial, visible result, where in some cases screenupdating is not automatically set to true.

Comment: @cyril thanks. Not many votes on that post. Still I don't understand. Until now I didn't turn it on, with no disadvantages. What happens if I don't put it on true?

Comment: @Prema At my first response to you, it was stated that `activate` and `select` reset the initial screen updating set to `false`.  By interacting with your worksheet, you are essentially "selecting" something.  What is brought up in the post I linked is, specifically, how the property may not be set back to `true`; this is where you see different behaviour from one user to the next where they may be unable to interact with their worksheet on scrolling, etc.  The safest option is to ensure you turn everything back on that you turned off.  Does that make more sense?